# Send Unicde "Clear Key" to GUI program on keypress

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Some apple keyboards have a "clear key" (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Keyboard)) that sends the unicode character U+2327. (This character is rendered as "⌧")

My keyboard does not have a clear key. I want to send the clear key to a GUI program. I tried using `xmodmap` to modify the keyboard layout to send U+2327:

```
me@myComputer:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep Num_Lock
keycode  77 = Num_Lock NoSymbol Num_Lock
me@myComputer:~$ xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = ⌧ Num_Lock"
xmodmap:  commandline:1:  bad keysym name '⌧' in keysym list
xmodmap:  1 error encountered, aborting.
```

I have tried to define a new keysym:

```
me@myComputer:~$ xmodmap -e "keysym Clear_Key = U2327"
xmodmap:  commandline:1:  bad keysym target key symbol 'Clear_Key'
xmodmap:  1 error encountered, aborting.
```

This did not work. How can I map my Num_Lock key (`keycode 77` above) to give a U+2327 character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unicode can be used directly in the xmodmap `keycode` directive:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = U2327 Num_Lock"
```

Comment: I would still be curious to learn how a new keysym can be defined...